# Even-odd multiplicative algebraic structure with idempotency?

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents, parity

**What is the algebraic structure for the multiplications of even elements and odd elements?**

Please notice that $o*o=o$, $e*e=e$ (idempotency) and $o\not = e$.

*1st structure is such that*

1. even times even is even.
2. even times odd is **odd**.
3. odd times odd is odd.

and its multiplicative matrix

```
*| o e 
--------- 
o| o o
e| o e
```

*2nd structure is such that*

1. even times even is even.
2. even times odd is **Even**.
3. odd times odd is odd.

and its multiplicative matrix

```
*| O E 
--------- 
O| O E
E| E E
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Map even to 0 and odd to 1.  It has the structure of a multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_2 / \{0\}$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven can you clarify the comment in an aswer?

Comment: @MorganRodgers sorry about typos, I had initially contradictions between the matrices and descriptions -- hopefully it is now consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation is associative, but you are confusing identity and idempotent. One has $oo = o$ and $ee = e$ and hence both $o$ and $e$ are idempotent. However $oe = eo = e$ and $oo = o$. Thus $o$ is an identity. The resulting structure is a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

Comment: I am not sure to understand. In the examples, you mention that $e * o = e$.

Comment: Yes this is correct observation: Even times odd is even, not odd -- checking now where I made my fallacy, taking some time... +1

Comment: So what are idempotent commutative algebraic structures where $e\not = o$? First structure is such that $$ee=e,eo=oe=o,oo=o.$$ Second structure is such that $$ee=e, eo=oe=e,oo=o.$$

Comment: Both structures are isomorphic to the monoid $\{0,1\}$ under the usual multiplication of integers (where $1$ is the identity). Isomorphism for the first structure: $f(e) = 1$, $f(o) = 0$. Isomorphism for the second structure: $g(e) = 0$, $g(o) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a field of two elements, $0,1$ with $0\neq 1$, we have the addition structure

$$0+0=0$$ $$ 0+1=1$$ $$1+0=1$$ $$1+1=0$$

the multiplication structure differs for fields; we don't consider the inclusion of $0$ in the structure because there are no zero divisors.  And again, we have

$$0\cdot 0=0$$ $$0\cdot 1=0$$ $$1\cdot 0=0$$ $$1\cdot 1=1$$

Now $0\mapsto e$ and $1\mapsto o$.

Comment: So the first structure $(\mathbb F_2,+)$ is a group while the second structure $(\mathbb F_2 / \{0\},*)$ is a monoid. Do you mean there is no zero divisors in the second structure?

Comment: Yes.  There are no nonzero elements whose product is 0.